# how can i read page number 2 in docx file by C# or .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

**i'm trying to iterate on docx file pages and read content page by page. any help?

Comment: “Any help?” is [not a useful question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Word documents don't work like that. A word document is more of a website (bunch of xml tags) than a bunch of specific pages with elements attached. The program(s) (Microsoft Office, Open Office) just give you the illusion of there being actual pages.

You could do this if you knew a page was going to x in length and never deviate... but that's rarely the case.

I could be wrong, but I've looked at 2 libraries in-depth and all of them can't do that.

Have a look at the documentation for Aspose.Words